# Cannot connect to Mariadb database remotely with mariadb-client (mysql-client works)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-cli

I have a remote server running MariaDB 10.6 database. I have all credentials.

I have tried regular connection command line on my PC and it works **perfectly**: `mysql -P3307 -hmyurl.com -u myuser -pmypass mydatabase`. However when I try it in Docker in Ubuntu I'm getting

> Access denied for user 'myuser '@'10.62.193.7' (using password: YES)

After quite some debugging, I figured out that the error appears only if I use `apt install mariadb-client` (either on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04). If I install `apt install mysql-client` it works perfectly.

Is there anything I can do to make `mariadb-client` working? I also use it somehow from Python (`mysqlclient`) and it seems to rely on mariadb-client as well, so I cannot basically connect from Python in this case...

P.S. I do not have admin control over the database server, so I cannot modify settings of the database.

Comment: Simply using the `-P` option doesn't necessarily make the client connect via TCP, but you must connect via TCP when using Docker. The default is to connect via UNIX domain socket, which can only connect to a local process; it can't connect to a Docker container. So try with the `--protocol=tcp` flag.

Comment: @BillKarwin I thought the access denied error implies that the client could connect to mariadb/mysql server, it's the authentication piece that was unsuccessful.

Comment: @TheGodfather: does the user mentioned in the error message have access to the given database in the given mariadb instance?

Comment: @Shadow, Yes, the error comes from _an_ instance of MySQL or MariaDB, but I'm supposing that it's not the one running in Docker. I think the OP has another instance running on their local computer, in addition to the Docker one.

Comment: @BillKarwin unix_socket will be used only if --socket was specified, if no hostname was specified or if hostname == 'localhost'. Option --protocol=TCP always uses TCP.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, the OP is using `-h` in the example they show. I'm still guessing that the user & password is not correct for the instance they are connecting to.

Comment: @Shadow yes, the user has all permissions, as mentioned, absolutely the same command (copy-paste) works if `mysql` is coming from `mysql-client`.

Comment: @BillKarwin another instance is not running on my computer, but somewhere remote. But this doesn't really matter, I believe, as it works when using mysql from `mysql-client`

Comment: > So try with the --protocol=tcp flag.

Tried, no success (not sure whether it should have helped, as the same command line works if I install mysql client...)

Comment: Even if the command is copy-paste, the database user could end up being different - e.g.. when mariadbclient connects it cannot resolve the IP address and when mysqlclient connects, it can resolve the IP address. These can be different users on the database side.

Comment: @Shadow I feel like I'm lost, not sure what actionably I can do here. User from the error is exactly the user from command line...

Comment: In the command line you provided myuser as username. The error message says access denied to myusername@ipaddress. If the mysql client can get mariadb to resolve the ip address, the connection may be made with myuser@hostname. These are two different users. One may have access, while the other one may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after many hours of digging, I figured out the solution, thanks to the colleague of mine.

**TLDR**:
The root cause of this was the configuration of the server which enforces TLSv1.2 and `mariadb-client` which does not like it by default.

More details:

> The mariadb-client only enables TLS by default (`--ssl` flag) with
> versions greater than 10.10.  Prior to that, it would not enable TLS
> unless you specify that flag.
>
> The guess is that your installed version of the `mariadb-client` is
> not setting SSL/TLS mode.  Failure to connect with encryption WILL
> result in the "Access Denied for user" error message, since
> unencrypted connections are disallowed.
>
> I would highly recommend that you explicitly set these parameters:
>
> mysql-client:  `--ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA   --ssl-ca=/path/to/ca/chain/file`
>
> mariadb-client: `--ssl  --ssl-verify-server-cert  --ssl-ca=/path/to/ca/chain/file`

So when I added single `--ssl` parameter to the call when using `mariadb-client`, to my surprise, it actually worked!